# Adding Double Variable values Using XYDataset(JFreeChart) to XySeries

Tags: java, jfreechart

"I have a Problem of adding double variable "gdataset" values to "series.add()". Any help please regarding this"

```
  private static XYDataset samplexydataset2() {
  double[][]gdataset;
  XYSeriesCollection xySeriesCollection = new XYSeriesCollection(); 
  XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Distances");
  gdataset= test.generateDataset();//which calls Method in other Class        
  for(int row=0;row<gdataset.length;row++)
    {
        for(int column=0;column<gdataset[row].length;column++)
        {

            series.add(gdataset[row],gdataset[column]);//I am getting error at "add" 
            //System.out.printf("%f" +"       ",gdataset[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        xySeriesCollection.addSeries(series); 
        return  xySeriesCollection;
    }
```

Thanks..U are correct!...what if I have another 3/4 Columns.So I want to make it Dynamic.
For Example:
My OuptPut looks like (X,Y)

```
      0.611787       2.304051       
      1.636265       2.261579       
      1.073176       1.188980
```

and If I have 3 Colums(X,Y,Z) its like this

```
       0.142197        1.440918       0.217366       
       0.149352        0.748124       3.214357       
       0.536232        0.107004       4.198831
```

And in this Way my Columns will be Increasing..So i want to put another For loop in this way and Display on the ScatterPlot.Any suggestions reg this will be helpful.

```
 for(int column=0;column<gdataset[row].length;column++)
        {

            //series.add(gdataset[row][column],gdataset[row][column++]); 
          }
```

Comment: What's your error? Compiler error? Runtime stack trace? If so can you give us it

Comment: It was Compile Error.//The method add(double, double) in the type XYSeries is not applicable for the arguments (double[], double[])//

Comment: I'd suggest opening a new question on `X,Y,Z` data; you'd need to use a different renderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the structure of `gdataset` is one *xy* pair per row, it looks like you meant to say:

```
for (int row = 0; row < gdataset.length; row++) {
    series.add(gdataset[row][0], gdataset[row][1]);
}
xySeriesCollection.addSeries(series); 
return xySeriesCollection;
```